# can we create pop-up windows using Freemarker Template Language (FTL)?

Tags: freemarker, popupwindow

can we create pop-up windows using Freemarker Template Language (FTL)?
If so, please point to any resources to check out...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. As per the site rules, questions that ask for direction to a tutorial, library, or other off-site resource are off topic for Stack Overflow. This is because Stack Overflow is intended to be a useful repository of actual programming questions rather than general ideas or tutorials. If you can rephrase your question in a way that makes it acceptable for the [ask] guidelines, please do!

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker runs on the server to generate the page that contains HTML and possibly JavaScript, then the JavaScript runs in the browser. So with JavaScript you can, just as on any HTML page.